# Why do the GWT plaintext components show rich-text?

Tags: gwt, xss

For safety against Cross Site Scripting,  "[it is preferred to use the non-HTML equivalent of widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html)" where richtext is not needed.

I generally want to interpret user input as plaintext.

The HTML at the center of the  `TextBox`  is just a `span`, and  renders in full as HTML.

```
<span class="text viewableValue"><b>x</b>y</span>
```

I am surprised at that because it does not implement `HasHTML` or `HasSafeHtml`.

What is the equivalent of `TextBox` (and all other `TextBoxBase` classes) that treats everything in it as plain text?

Comment: I think one of us is very confused - TextBox is an `<input type=text>`, and any user input set via `setText(...)` goes into the input's `value` attribute. Are you sure you're using a GWT TextBox and calling `setText` or `setValue`?

Comment: Quite right. I'm puzzled at that too. So are you saying that the span's *value* in this case should not be rendered as richtext but rathet presented at plaintext?

Comment: Definitely - even reading the code in the GWT TextBox.setText should make this quite clear - all it does is assign the value attribute of the input. There isn't even a span wrapper, I'm not sure how you managed to get a span tag, unless you are using some other TextBox that isn't part of GWT at all.

Comment: Thank you! You are of course right: I was looking at a `TextBox` used for input, but in view-only rendering of the same data, an `InlineHTML` was being used.